Blazor WASM StateHasChanged Only Fires One Time
I have an application using Blazor WASM. I have several components that are disparate and need to communicate with each other when certain events take place.
I created a message service that allows me to fire messages from one component and subscribing components can subscribe to the events.
Most of the time, the only thing that needs to take place is that one component needs to tell another component to re-render after an update.
My current scenario and where I'm having a problems is as follows:

I have a main page that hosts a few components.
One of the components on that page is a modal dialog that allows a user to update some data (an adventure).
When the modal is done updating, it fires an event notifying subscribers that it fired. Subscribers then call StateHasChanged to update their component UI.

The problem is, StateHasChanged will only ever be called one time and subsequent calls do nothing. The event fires every time, StateHasChanged is called every time, but the UI only updates the first time StateHasChanged is called.
I have tried setting various values on the component, using async instead of void and everything I can think of to cause the re-render to no avail.
The message service:
public interface IMessageService
{
    event Action<string> OnMessage;
    event Func<string, Task> OnMessageAsync;
    void SendMessage(string message);
    void ClearMessages();
}

public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    public event Action<string> OnMessage;
    public event Func<string, Task> OnMessageAsync;

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        OnMessage?.Invoke(message);
    }

    public void ClearMessages()
    {
        OnMessage?.Invoke(null);
    }
}

Code block for the modal dialog
@code {
    [Parameter] public entities.Adventure Adventure { get; set; }
    private bool isBusy = false;
    private DateTime startDate;
    private DateTime endDate;
    private int numberOfDays;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //capture the original start and end dates so we can deetected if they have been altered
        startDate = Adventure.StartDate;
        endDate = Adventure.EndDate;
        numberOfDays = (endDate - startDate).Days;
    }

    private async Task OnSubmit()
    {
        try
        {
            isBusy = true;
            bool isDateChange = false;

            if (startDate != Adventure.StartDate || endDate != Adventure.EndDate)
            {
                if ((Adventure.EndDate - Adventure.StartDate).Days != numberOfDays)
                {
                    await DialogService.Alert("Your trip does not contain the same number of days. You will loose some of your itinerary items (tasks, activities, etc). Please select a date range with the same number of days as your original adventure. You can remove days individually later if necessary.", "Oops", new AlertOptions() { OkButtonText = "Okay" });
                    isBusy = false;

                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    isDateChange = true;
                }
            }

            var updatedAdventure = await AdventureClient.UpdateAdventureDetails(Adventure, isDateChange);

            MessageService.SendMessage("AdventureUpdated");

            DialogService.Close(updatedAdventure);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DialogService.Alert($"Something went wrong while trying to save your adventure {ex.Message}", "Oops", new AlertOptions() { OkButtonText = "Close" });
        }
        finally
        {
            isBusy = false;
        }
    }
}

The code block for the hosting page that needs to be re-rendered
@code {
    [Parameter] public Guid Id { get; set; }

    private entities.Adventure? adventure;
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        MessageService.OnMessage += MessageHandler;
        await GetAdventure();
    }

    async Task GetAdventure()
    {
        try
        {
            adventure = await AdventureClient.GetAdventure(Id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DialogService.Alert($"Something went wrong while trying to fetch your adventure {ex.Message}", "Oops", new AlertOptions() { OkButtonText = "Close" });
        }
    }

    private void MessageHandler(string message)
    {
        if (message != null && message == "AdventureUpdated")
        {
            //BUG: this only gets called the first time the modal updates and does not get called on subsequent modal updates. The event fires every time
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MessageService.OnMessage -= MessageHandler;
    }
}


There are situations where having a messaging service in a Blazor Webassembly application is needed.  This isn't one of those situations.  That said, if MessageHandler is being called every time, the only thing that will prevent StateHasChanged from executing are your if conditions.

Setting a breakpoit on StateHasChanged hits every time. The conditional logic is not the problem.

I guarantee StateHasChanged is called.  You're expectation is it forces an immediate render.  That's not what happens.  What it does is queue a RenderFragment on the Renderer Queue, That queue is serviced by the UI Thread (the Synchronisation Context), which may or may not be busy at the time.
Either:

(Unlikely) The UI thread is blocked after the first render.
The component is rendered, but the data it's rendering hasn't changed. [You haven't shown that].

You can test if the page is rendering using this code in the page content:
@($"Rendered at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}")


You are correct that StateHasChanged is in fact being called. I used that snippet and it proves it. So, my data binding is failing somewhere. The updates to my Adventure object are only updating one time then no more.

This turned out to be a problem with my bindings in components.
